# Module not found: Error: You attempted to import , problems with relative import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:0-30

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../main/App which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from '../main/App';              (**My problem is here**)
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear, what are you having trouble with? You would appear to be doing this at the top level of your `src` directory, so `../main/App` will take you out of the area your bundler (whatever is giving you that error) expects to find code in. Maybe you meant `./main/App`? What's your directory structure? What file is this in? Where is the `main/App` file?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with [tag:react-hooks], [tag:jsx], or [tag:react-native] (as you're clearly using `ReactDOM`). (And really, doesn't have anything to do with [tag:reactjs], but one can see why you'd include it.) Please only use relevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the solution is in error so bring your App.js or main folder inside of the src folder and then  it works

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from '../main/App';  
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```